# Converting an integer to an hexadecimal unsigned char array in C++

Tags: c++, integer, hex, unsigned-char

I need to convert an integer `int parameter` to an hexadecimal unsigned char `buffer[n]`.
If integer is for example 10 then the hexadecimal unsigned char array should be 0x0A

To do so I have the following code:

```
int parameter;
std::stringstream ss;
unsigned char buffer[];

ss << std::hex << std::showbase << parameter;
typedef unsigned char byte_t;

byte_t b = static_cast<byte_t>(ss); //ERROR: invalid static_cast from type ‘std::stringstream {aka std::basic_stringstream<char>}’ to type ‘byte_t {aka unsigned char}’

buffer[0]=b;
```

Does anyone know how to avoid this error?
If there is a way of converting the integer parameter into an hexadecimal unsigned char than doing first: `ss << std::hex << std::showbase << parameter;` that would be even better.

Comment: FYI: an unsigned char is just a single character. Your wording is quite confusing.

Comment: Numbers aren't hexadecimal. `10` and `0xa` represent the same number. If you want a character that is the hexadecimal representation of ten, that would be `'a'`.

Comment: Yes, I want the same number represented in hexadecimal and assigned to a unsigned char buffer[n]. Appending '0x' is done to show the base, and it is a requirement. Any idea of how to do it?

Comment: `byte_t b = static_cast<byte_t>(ss);` is completely nonsensical. Do you want to have something like a `union Int32Bytes { int ival; byte_t bytes[4]; };` actually?

Answer (score 1):

Consulting my psychic powers it reads you actually want to have a `int` value seen in it's representation of bytes (`byte_t`). Well, as from your comment

> I want the same number represented in hexadecimal and assigned to a unsigned char buffer[n].

not so much psychic powers, but you should note hexadecimal representation is a matter of formatting, not internal integer number representation.

The easiest way is to use a `union` like

```
union Int32Bytes { 
    int ival; 
    byte_t bytes[sizeof(int)]; 
};
```

and use it like

```
Int32Bytes x;
x.ival = parameter;

for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(int); ++i) {
    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << (int)x.bytes[i] << ' ';
}
```

Be aware to see unexpected results due to endianess specialities of your current CPU architecture.

Comment: Won't you get `0x0 0x0 0x0 0xa` or `0xa 0x0 0x0 0x0` depending on the endianness of the system ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: `buffer` is of undetermined size in your snippet.  I'll suppose that you have declared it with a sufficient size.

Problem 2:  the result of your conversion will be several chars (at least 3 due to the `0x` prefix).  So you need to copy all of them.  This won't work with an `=` unless you'd have strings.

Problem 3:  your intermediary cast won't succeed:  you can't hope to convert a complex stringstream object to a single unsigned char.  Fortunately, you don't need this.

Here a possible solution using [`std::copy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/), and adding a null terminator to the buffer:

```
const string& s = ss.str();
*copy(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), buffer)='\0';
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/dxMR1H)